# If H2 has more than one word, than wrap last word with span

Tags: jquery

Is it possible with jQuery wrap last word inside `h2` tag if it have more than word.

For example.

If:

```
<h2>Example</h2>
```

than do nothing

But if:

```
<h2>This is next example</h2>
```

than wrap last word with span.

```
<h2>This is next <span>example</span></h2>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$("h2").html(function(){

  // separate the text by spaces
  var text= $(this).text().split(" ");

  // drop the last word and store it in a variable
  var last = text.pop();

  // join the text back and if it has more than 1 word add the span tag
  // to the last word
  return text.join(" ") + (text.length > 0 ? " <span>"+last+"</span>" : last);   

});
```

**See demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/VHDpT/1/

Answer (score 1):

You should probably be able to do something like this:

```
$("h2").each(function () {
    var html = $(this).html();
    var split = html.split(" ");
    if (split.length > 1) {
        split[split.length - 1] = "<span>" + split[split.length - 1] + "</span>"
        $(this).html(split.join(" "));
    }
});
```

By splitting it apart, you can check if there's more than one word and then adjust the last one to be wrapped in a span.